# Backbone: mixin events extends from extending view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, mixins

I have this mixin that is used by many views

```
var EditTableRowMixin = {
   events: {
     "click .save": "save",
     "click .abort": "abort"
   },

   /* common methods for table rows */
};
```

Now I have a new view that needs a couple more events than this mixin has:

```
var SpecialRowEditView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : "div",

    events: {
        "click .remove" : "remove",
        "click .add" : "add"
    },
    initialize: function(){
       /*Do things */
    },
    ...
    ...
    ...            
  });
_.extend(SpecialRowEditView.prototype, EditTableRowMixin);
return SpecialRowEditView;
```

I have tried to just add these events to this.events (which is the mixins events). It works, but breaks all the other views using the mixin because those now look for the save and abort functions for some reason.

How can I extend the mixin's events with the ones I need for this view only?

Comment: you can try like `SpecialRowEditView = SpecialRowEditView.extend( EditTableRowMixin )`

Answer (score 0):

```
var more_events = {
        events: {
          "click .remove" : "remove",
          "click .add" : "add"
        }
    },

_.extend(SpecialRowEditView.prototype, _.merge(EditTableRowMixin, more_events));
```

your events is overridden by mixin. you need merge them together.
here i use [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#merge) in place of underscore.